# What is the error OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : javascript error: document.getElementByName is not a function

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I got a error in executing the below line of code

```cs
driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\hp\Documents\Driver");
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://demo.guru99.com/v3/");
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementByName('uid').value ='mngr303517'");
js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementByName('password').value='ujudysY'");
js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementByName('btnLogin').click()");
```

I got the error At line 3

> document.getElementByName is not a function (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.141)

what is the reason for it?

Comment: It should be `getElementsByName` [see here](https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/JavaScript/DOM/Document/getElementsByName). You are missing an 's', its plural and returns an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript method is document.getElement**s**ByName(...) (plural - Elements not Element).

This method returns a collection of elements, not a single element.

```
js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementsByName('uid')[0].value ='mngr303517'");
```

Be sure to access the `[0]` index of the collection before calling the `value` property.

It might be a little cleaner to use `document.querySelector` instead:

```cs
js.ExecuteScript(@"document.querySelector(""[name='uid']"").value ='mngr303517'");
js.ExecuteScript(@"document.querySelector(""[name='password']"").value='ujudysY'");
js.ExecuteScript(@"document.querySelector(""[name='btnLogin']"").click()");
```

Comment: yes i got it thank you so much it was my mistake